# Json not working with angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get forecast information from an external domain, which doesn't seem to work yet. Both Angular and jQuery are loaded, but nothing shows up in HTML. Chrome doesn't report an error message either.

```
        var currentCityread = "Eindhoven";
        var api1 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q='+currentCityread+'&cnt=10&mode=json&units=metric&APPID=000000000000000&callback=?';
        var api2 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+currentCityread+'&mode=json&units=metric&APPID=000000000000000&callback=?'
        function ReadJson($scope) {
            $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: api1,
              }).done(function (output) {
                $scope.jsonTotal = output.list[0].temp.day+output.list[1].temp.day+output.list[2].temp.day+output.list[3].temp.day+output.list[4].temp.day+output.list[5].temp.day+output.list[6].temp.day+output.list[7].temp.day+output.list[8].temp.day+output.list[9].temp.day;
                $scope.jsonCalcu = Math.round($scope.jsonTotal / 10);
                $scope.jsonCurrent = Math.round(output.list[0].temp.day);
                $scope.jsonCurrent2 = Math.round(output.list[1].temp.day);
                $scope.jsonCurrenticon2 = output.list[1].weather[0].icon;
                $scope.jsonCurrent3 = Math.round(output.list[2].temp.day);
                $scope.jsonCurrenticon3 = output.list[2].weather[0].icon;
            });
            $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: api2,
              }).done(function (outputcurrent) {
                $scope.jsonCurrenticon = outputcurrent.weather[0].icon;
            });
        }
```

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply()` inside the done method callback, after the assignment

Comment: where is this code? is ReadJson a controller? otherwise I don't know how you can inject scope there. In any case, why not using `$http` ?

Comment: I don't think jquery ajax can work with angular's scope. use $http instead

Comment: This code is an external javascript file. ReadJson is a controller indeed. $http won't do the trick as that might be insecure, cross domain:).

Comment: It makes no sense. They are pretty much at the same secure level. The point is you can't use jQuery to access Angularjs scope like this.

Comment: @Chandermani Your comment solved the problem. Too bad a comment can't be an answer;). If you post it down there \/ I'll mark this problem as solved:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the scope after a callback which is outside the angular execution context, you need to use `$scope.$apply()`.

But as others have mentioned in their comments `$http` can be used, with JSONP as the request is cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think same-origin policy forbids you from performing cross-domain query. What you can do is to perform the query on the server side, and return the result to the browser. Another workaround is to use jsonp. But it is not recommended due to its insecure nature.